# Cannot render PartialView in modal popup (Kendo window)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, modal-dialog, partial-views, popupwindow

In my MVC application I open a popup window after clicking Create button, but I cannot render my partialview render in it. What I want to do is simply **render partialview** in the popup dialog and **pass model and some parameters** (i.e. id=1) to it. Could you please tell me where is the mistake? Thanks in advance.

**Note:** Any solution using **bootstrap modal** would also been appreciated...

**View:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("CreateWindow")
    .Title("Create Employee")
    .Visible(false)
    .Draggable(true)
    .LoadContentFrom("_Create", "Employee")
    .Width(800)
    .Modal(true)
    .Content("Loading Part List Info...")
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
)


<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    // When your button is clicked
    $('#createbtn').click(function () {
        var createWindow = $('#CreateWindow').data('kendoWindow');
        createWindow.center().open();
    });
});
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult _Create()
{
    var model = repository.Employee;
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

**PartialView:**

```
@model Employee

<div>MY PARTIAL VIEW CONTENT GOES HERE ...</div>
```

Comment: I've tried your code and it's working fine for me. Just missing the closed `</script>` tag at the end of your View.

Comment: Actually, there is no missing tag in my project and I added the missing tag to above as well. On the other hand, the dialog is opened, but the content from partialview is not rendered and model data cannot be retrieved to the modal window. Any idea?

Comment: As it seems to work for me and not for you, I think the problem must be elsewhere. Have you, just in case, some potential related JavaScript error(s) from you navigator? (from your example, in my side, I can pass model data to the PartialView and display them well into this one)

Comment: I don't like to use the `content` property to request a partial content. I use the jQuery's `load()` method on the content div, then after content loaded I show the window.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Could you please post your example code by making necessary modifications on the code above? Promise, I will not vote down :)

Comment: @Banov I retried again, but although the modal is opened, the partialview cannot be rendered in it. On thy other hand, there is no error on the firebug console before and after opening the modal window. On the other hand when debugging, the code does not hit the _Cretate method in the controller. Is there anything to call the method in the javascript i.e. url?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my working code, hoping it will help you:

**View:**

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Test"; }
@Styles.Render("~/Content/kendoui/css")

<input type="button" id="createbtn" value="Test kWindow"/>

@(Html.Kendo().Window()
    .Name("CreateWindow")
    .Title("Create Employee")
    .Visible(false)
    .Draggable(true)
    .LoadContentFrom("_Create", "Employee", new { id = 1 })
    .Width(800)
    .Modal(true)
    .Content("Loading Part List Info...")
    .Draggable()
    .Resizable()
)

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendoui")
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function () {
    // When your button is clicked
    $('#createbtn').click(function () {
        var createWindow = $('#CreateWindow').data('kendoWindow');
        createWindow.center().open();
    });
});
</script>
```

**PartialView:**

```
@model Banov.Controllers.Employee
<div>MY PARTIAL VIEW CONTENT GOES HERE ...</div>
<div>@(Model.Id)</div>
<div>@(Model.FirstName)</div>
<div>@(Model.LastName)</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace Banov.Controllers
{
    public class EmployeeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult _Create(int id)
        {
            var model = new Employee
                    {
                        Id = id,
                        FirstName = "John",
                        LastName = "Doe"
                    };
            return PartialView(model);
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Actually it was not working for the first attempt after trying your posted code, but I realized that when making debugging, the code hits the breakpoint on the javascript line and after disabling the breakpoint it worked (I think the main problem was not loading the kendo grid properly and it causes some problem regarding to javascript). Anyway, I hope this answer will also be helpful for the others. Thanks again. Voted+